# IMU Vision Fusion using EKF

Tags: kalman-filter, imu, ekf, pose

I am trying to track an object indoors using an IMU (only accel and gyroscope) and a visual marker. This is similar to IMU+GPS fusion, where GPS is effectively replaced by the position that my vision based system gives based on the marker.
I am writing an error EFK to fuse the two readings. I am including the accel and gyro biases as part of my state estimation as well, to reduce the drift caused by IMU in between measurements. For the same, I have a couple of queries.

1. What are the jacobians for the state uncertainty propogation in the prediction step. Here are my notations:

   P = F * P * F.t() + G * L * G.t()

where

- P is my state covariance matrix (15x15) - 3 for position, 3 for
  velocity, 4 for orientation (quaternion) and 6 for accel and gyro
  biases
- F is the jacobian of prediction model. It should be of size 15x15. For the first 9 rows, it is straightforward, however, I am not sure about the last 6 rows (that correspond to the biases)
- L is the variance and bias variances of the accel and the gyroscope (12x12) (a simple diagonal matrix)
- Finally G is the jacobian associated with the noise and biases. I am not sure what this should be as well. It should be a (15x12) matrix. The first 3 rows are zeros, but dont know how to fill the rest of the matrix. Is this also a simple diagonal matrix (from row 4) with values `1` in the diagonal? I am confused primarily about this matrix.

Any help on deriving these jacobian matrices would be very helpful!

Finally, will my method work? I.e. I follow a pipeline similar to IMU+GPS fusion, however I replace the GPS component with my visual marker position estimate.

Comment: To find the Jacobian you'll have to start with the equations of motion. Do you have these?

Comment: The best paper about Error State EKFs is the [seminal paper by Joan Sola](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02508.pdf). Lucky for you he derives all of the jacobians and other equations for an IMU+GPS based system.

Comment: Hello @holmeski I have the equations of the model, but not accounting for bias, so that is where I am stuck

Comment: Hi @edwinem thanks a ton! I'll check it out

Comment: Hi @edwinem thanks for the resource. I implemented the filter as is given there, however, I was not very successful. The position given by my IMU (motion model) seems to drift very rapidly even for a window of 2 seconds. I increasingly feel that IMU may not be the right solution, but literature says otherwise. Any tips on the same?

Comment: IMU translation is always terrible due to it providing acceleration information and the double integration you have to do. 2 seconds is large enough that I would expect it to drift a significant amount. You really do need to have the visual update happen also at a pretty high rate. At least 1-2 times a second. I would also double check that you are doing everything correctly by looking at the rotation. If the rotation drifts a lot then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi @edwinem.I am using the visual update only to correct for the position (translation), and the rotation drift for a period of one minute seems to be fairly manageable. I presume that my implementation may be right, since orientation is obtained purely using IMU in my code. The issue is that sometimes vision measurement may be lost for a couple of seconds, and I primarily need the IMU in those cases to track it correctly. What other alternatives would you suggest? Thanks!